# How to iterate through a json array with the following structure

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json structure:

```
 Object 
    data: Array[1]
       0:Object
         categories: Object
            cat: namecat
            cat2: namecate2
         errors: Object
            err1: error1
            err2: error2
         name: NAMEOFTHETHING
       1:Object
         categories: Object
            cat: namecat
            cat2: namecate2
         errors: Object
            err1: error1
            err2: error2
         name: NAMEOFTHETHING
```

Using JavaScript, I need to get the array of the values into categories, also another array with the errors values, and finally the name.

Can you please point on the right direction to iterate into it??

**UPDATE**

So far I've tried this, said my json string is saved on a var called **result**

```
 for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    var obj = result[i];
    console.log(obj);
 }
```

This is the way I thought it should work, however it is loggin character by character, I was specting having each key separated, however.... nono

Comment: Have you given this a shot? Can you share what you have tried? Can you post the actual JSON string?

Comment: Draw the object structure of the output you would like to see just like you drew the structure of the input we are processing. This stuff is easy to do, but we don't know what final result you're expecting to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `result` is a JSON string, you have to first call `JSON.parse(result)` to turn the string into a JS object, and can then loop over its `data` property (the array).

Currently you are iterating over the characters of the JSON string, using a non standard feature (bracket access for characters of an array)

```
var arr = JSON.parse(result).data
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}

// or
JSON.parse(result).data.forEach(function(obj, index){
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: You can also use `$.each()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop.  If you are fetching the json string from an ajax call then specifying the json return type properly will result in it being parsed automagically.  If you need to support old browsers use `$.parseJSON` instead of `JSON.parse`